# Using local variable in inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am curious about why we cannot use local variables of a method inside an anonymous inner class declared in the same method. The reason that the variable is removed from the call stack after method completes while the reference to the inner class may continue to exist does not seem justifying to me.

My Doubts:

1. If the class cannot be instantiated outside the method than what could be the reason for    not letting it use the local variables?
2. Why does making the argument final make it acceptable? Are these not on the call stack as well?
3. Since the inner class cannot be instantiated outside the method, how can a reference to the inner class be passed to another method and how can it be assigned to a reference variable in another method? What is the type of the variable that it can be assigned to?

Here's an example:

```
public class MyOuter2 {

    int num = 1;                    //Outer instance variable

    void doStuff(final int x) {     //Outer instance Method with final variable

//      void doStuff( int x) {      //Final removed,  compiler error


        class MyInner {                 //Outer Method inner class

            public void seeOuter() {
                System.out.println("Outer num=" + num);
                System.out.println(x);
            }

        }

        MyInner inner = new MyInner();
        inner.seeOuter();
        readInnerObject(inner);             //any method that pass inner object

    }




    public void readInnerObject(Object i ){

        MyOuter2 outer = new MyOuter2();    // how to receive it???????????

        }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MyOuter2 o = new MyOuter2();
        o.doStuff(2);
    }

}
```

Comment: PLEASE gives us a code sample that is cleanly formatted. You are shooting yourself in the foot by making us work to understand your sample.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the inner class can run after the enclosing method has exited, and the local variables no longer exist on the call stack. Consequently, a copy of their values needs to be made. Doing this when the inner class is instantiated is easiest to understand and implement.

> If the class cannot be instantiated outside the method than what could be the reason of not letting it use the local variables?

Because the local variables may no longer exist on the call stack when the code of the inner class is run.

> Why making the argument final makes it acceptable? does not these go with the stack?

Because such values can be copied without any worry about when they're copied.

> How the reference of the inner class if passed to other method going to get assigned to what type of variable if the inner class cannot be instantiated outside the method?

You can refer to the inner class by a superclass or an interface that the inner class extends or implements.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow. You can accept one answer that you find most useful by clicking the checkmark to the left. You can upvote multiple answers you find useful by clicking the up-triangle to the left.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 3, you *cannot* pass instances of `MyInner` to other methods because they do not know what the `MyInner` class is. In more realistic examples, `MyInner` will implement an interface or extend some superclass. This would allow you to pass an instance of `MyInner` to other methods by using them by assigning it to a reference variable that is declared as the type of the interface or superclass.